# ITEXT dataElements Loop Performance

Tags: java, performance, itext, report, itext7

Hi recently I'm working on a project and one of the reporting module is using iText 2.0.8 version library. Everything work fine until the number of data became huge (around 50,000+ of row). I really need suggestion from every expert on Stackoverflow to improve my code.

My code logic: I wrote HTML code with all data contained inside. After the full HTML code is done, it will store into a variable called as "content", then I'll convert the "content" variable into IElement list and perform a for loop to add into the document. I realise this loop is causing a bad performance (CPU usage is high) and the report is generating very slow (even caused connection timeout).

The following the part of code that caused a very high CPU usage for Java process.

```
//The **content** String variable is contain the HTML code of the report
//(From <head> to <body> with <table> as the main content to structure the data row).
//I didnt include here because the code is huge.

    String PDFFileName = "123.pdf";
    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileOutputStream(PDFFileName)));
    Document document = new Document(pdf);

    List<IElement> dataElements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(content.toString(), converterProperties);
        for (IElement element : dataElements) {
            if (element instanceof IBlockElement) {
                document.add((IBlockElement) element);
            }
        }
```

I know the loop is the issue, but I don't any other way is better and efficient for my case, hope someone can help me on this! Thank you. Please comment below if need extra information (Sorry cant really include all the code since it's very huge).

Specification: itext 2.0.8, Java 8.0, HTML, CSS.

Comment: Your code looks like iText 7.x, not 2.x.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you first create the table as HTML instead of as an iText `Table`? For the latter option there are optimization options...